# gradle javadoc fail on UTF-8 chars, only on windows

Tags: java, gradle

So i have a gradle based java project, with tons of hungarian docs string, witch mean a lot of non ASCII character.

It's perfectly fine since javac consume utf-8 characters in source code,and javadoc also should according to my knowledge.

In the build gradle has a task which create the java doc jar

```
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
```

When i run `gradle build`, it's fail with the following error:

> :compileJava
>   C:\Home\Projects\InventoryCore\src\main\java\hu\rfit\inventory\models\entities\ItemState.java:11:
>   error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252  * ├?ru / term├⌐k
>   ├íllapot.
>       ^ :processResources UP-TO-DATE :classes :jar :javadoc C:\Home\Projects\InventoryCore\src\main\java\hu\rfit\inventory\models\entities\ItemState.java:11:
>   error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252  * ├?ru / term├⌐k
>   ├íllapot.
>       ^ 1 error :javadoc FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':javadoc'.
>   Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): 'C:\Home\Projects\InventoryCore\build\tmp\javadoc\javadoc.options'

The best part is it's running perfectly in build pipeline, and on my other os (ubuntu 16.04 lts) it's fail only on windows.

I have already tried a fresh clone of the git repo, updated the the java jdk to the newest(oracle jdk 1.8.0_131 before was a _73 and _111 tried both).
All the files in the project are utf-8 encoded, and also tried put javadoc setting into my `build.gradle` file,

```
javadoc {
    options.charSet = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want

```
options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

That would fit with the javadoc help text of:

```
-encoding <name>                 Source file encoding name
```

... whereas `charSet` appears to affect the *output*. (I'd hope it would default to UTF-8 already..)